# Huge layer takes too long to load and it's hindering my workflow

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.2, performance, insar

I have a huge point shapefile of InSAR data, on the heighs of 300k+ points in a single shapefile, over a large area. My workflow consists in manually checking and ensuring the quality of some points; however, since there's new data every month, I have to do this process very often.
My problem lies in how long the layer takes to load after zooming in or out - sometimes it taker upwards of 40 seconds. As you see, this makes the whole process very inefficient.

Is there some way to make this layer load faster?

My computer is OK, having a GPU and all, and 32Gb of RAM, a Ryzen 5 processor, 3.2GHz. I can't upgrade this software because, well, this is the company's hardware.

Comment: Add a spatial index if it doesn't have one already.   Have the project in the same coordinate system as your data to avoid on the fly projection costs.   If you have the locations you will be checking in another layer you could stay zoomed in and then use the table of this second layer to pan from one point to another to avoid zooming in and out.  If the locations are the same location time after time then you could bookmark them and then go from one of those to the next.

Comment: In addition to @John's tips, writing the features to a File Geodatabase and using that instead of the Shapefile will probably drastically improve performance.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS 10.2 but your question does not mention whether you are using ArcMap 10.2 or something else.